# Neither Open nor Closed Sets via Preimage Argument

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

> Show that the set below is neither open nor closed. Do so by finding $f^{-1}(S)$ for the function $f$. Find a suitable function $f$ if no function is given.

$$S:=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3~\middle|~ \sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}\leqslant z<1\right\}$$

Comment: Could you clarify what $S$ is?  Namely, as stated I don't understand what it means.

Comment: that's my fault, there were a few typos @AlvinJin is that better?

Comment: Well, $S$ appears to be a cone that does not include the base, (if that is intended to be $z<1$), but does include the other surface (if $\surd(x^2+y^2)\leqslant z$ is intended), so....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - z$ restricted to $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\times [0,1)$.